# Issues with paginating search results in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to do searching and sorting with pagination in a page which displays a table from database. Initially the page displays all the records from the database along with pagination which is working fine. But as I implemented searching and sorting only the first page is showing the search/sort result. The remaining pages are showing all the records from the database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* code for pagination */
$no_of_record_per_page=2;

if(isset($_POST['btn_search']))
{
    $search_term = $_POST['txt_search_term'];
    $select_query = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_name like '%$search_term%'";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['btn_asc'])) 
{
    $sort_by = $_POST['ddl_sort_by'];
    $select_query = "select * from tbl_admin order by $sort_by  asc";  

}
elseif (isset($_POST['btn_desc'])) 
{

    $sort_by = $_POST['ddl_sort_by'];
    $select_query = "select * from tbl_admin order by $sort_by desc";   

}

else
{
    $select_query = "select * from tbl_admin";
}
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
$total_record=mysql_num_rows($result);
$max_page=ceil($total_record/$no_of_record_per_page);
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    $next_page = $page+1;
    $prev_page = $page-1;

    if($next_page>$max_page)
    {
        $next_page = $max_page;
    }
    if($prev_page<1)
    {
        $prev_page=1;
    }

}
else
{
    $page=1;
    $prev_page=1;
    $next_page=2;
    if($next_page > $max_page)$next_page = $max_page;
 }

$limit_page=$page-1;
    $limit = " LIMIT ".$no_of_record_per_page*$limit_page.",".$no_of_record_per_page;
?>
```

There is a text box for searching and buttons and drop down list for sorting.
This is the code that displays the record.

```
<?php
$select_query = $select_query.$limit;
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
  <tr>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $row['admin_id']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $row['admin_clg_id']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $row['admin_name']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $row['admin_mobile_no']; ?></td>
      <td class="center"><?php echo $row['admin_uname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
  }
 ?>
```

Could anyone identify my mistake. I am a beginner. Thanks
(I also know about datatable and similar plugins, but I want to learn to implement on my own once. So please do not suggest any plugin. )

Comment: 1) vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) 2) Failed to RTFM [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: The reason only the first page is showing the search/sorting results is because your next/prev buttons are running the 4th `$select_query`

Comment: @MarcB yes, I was using the depricated myql_query() in my original code. Someone suggested to use mysqli_query(). So i did that in the question. I have changed the question to my original code. Please read the edited question. Yes it has sql injection problems and uses depricated functions, But i want to know the issues with pagination.

Comment: @CptMisery Do you have any idea how to solve that. i guess isset('btn_search') is true only the first time we hit the search button

Comment: plus, that's an incredibly "heavy" way of doing pagination. "fetching everything" just to get a row count, then throw all away so you can run a limit query. you should go read up about `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

Comment: @MarcB Yes thank you

Comment: In the past when I've built my own paging, I added attributes to the next/prev buttons to hold the information I used to build the query.  So in your next button it would be something like this: `<button type="button" name="next" data-search="dave" data-sort="admin_name">Next</button>`